# Free Webasyst alternative

Tags: php

Is there any free alternative to webasyst  files http://www.webasyst.net/files/ script and webasyst notes.

Comment: Question should be asked on http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for online/Saas solutions, there are many alternatives (online sharing of documents)

Check out this link for many alternatives

http://alternativeto.net/desktop/sugarsync/?platform=online

Comment: Actually i was looking for a installable php script.

Comment: Check out Knowledgetree CMS. It comes both in paid and open source/free versions. Among other things, you can share one-time download links with users etc. I am not sure which features are paid for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have got ajaxplorer. It is a beautiful looking ajax script and it has ability to create user. It is free too. Also there is filerun but it costs $$.